# emacs hangs under windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, emacs, windows-registry

after using Emacs for a while, I frequently encounter hangup issues, e.g, when I try to move the cursor, the software just freezes for ~5 second before it can response.

I then used the Process Monitor from M$ http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx to check what is wrong, and I believe I found something but just don't know how to solve it.
the operation that causes the issue is:

RegOpenKey by emacs.exe, which is searching for a key in registry 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\CTF\KnownClasses', but NAME NOT FOUND

since there is no such key, i just added manually, and then the issue becomes:

RegQueryValue by emacs.exe, which is searching for a key in registry 
'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\CTF\KnownClasses\Emacs', but NAME NOT FOUND

Has anyone here know what is the root cause of this? or how should I add keys in registry to solve the issue?
thanks

Answer (score -1):

As always...

Can you reproduce the problem starting from `emacs -Q`, i.e., with no init file (~/.emacs)?

- If so, great. In that case, consider sending a bug report to Emacs Dev: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.  It is not normal for Emacs to hang.
- If not, *bisect your init file recursively* (e.g. commenting out 1/2, then 3/4, then 7/8, ...) until you find the root of the problem.  Then report that code here if you still have a question.

Comment: its not reproducible... sometimes i work days with emacs, and nothing happens, sometimes, from no where, it just happens... That is why i use process monitor to check what is really causing the problem, and found this registry issue in windows.

Comment: Why the downvote (11 years later)?